# How to add ScrollBar on wordpress front page

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to add a scroll bar to the page with directional buttons

```css
html {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.color-picker-main-container {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your HTML code? Thanks

Comment: I am using wordpress; this is the additional CSS code; I want to add a scrollbar within this code

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server? If yes then share the link. Thanks

Comment: trackyourbuild.com

Comment: I think you are using any third-party plugin for the scroll. The issue appeared because of that plugin it actually disabled the default scroll and for somehow the plugin scroll not working.

Comment: Okay Let me try to deactivate all scroll third-party plugins

Comment: I have deactivated all scroll bar plugins but still the same: I cannot seem to add a scroll bar using the additional css code

Comment: I just post my answer, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `!important` in `overflow: hidden` will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
html {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much